# React setState re-rendering three times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this useEffect to store both the orders and a userID. I wanted to get the userID stored in the document so I used the setID to store it. When I tried making a try...catch to get the user collection with that specific id, it would result an error saying that the `doc(id)` must not be empty. When I'll try to `console.log(id)`, it would render three times.

**The First render** - will be empty

**Second Render** - renders the userID

**Third Render** - render the userID

[image]

```
const details = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
  const [id, setID] = useState("");

  // to get the details
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firestore
      .collection("orders")
      .doc(Data)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        const arr = [];
        arr.push({
          id: snapshot.id,
          ...snapshot.data(),
        });
        setID(arr[0].userID);
        setOrders(arr);
      });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  console.log(id);

  return (
    <div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image]

How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Please share a screenshot of what that document looks like.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? It's supposed to be -rendering three times , initial render , then you are calling `setID` so that will cause a render and then `setOrders(arr);` will cause a render too

Comment: @Dharmaraj added it already

Comment: @Cybershadow the problem is whenever I'll try to fetch the user collection from firestore, it would say the the .doc must not be empty, meaning, it only reads the first render of the setID which is an empty string, hence, it is causing an error

Comment: @JenJennie Where are you trying to fetch the user collection? please add that code

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem, there is another function that you are using the `id` as a parameter and it's being called in the first render and it's empty.

You could create and `useEffect` for this effect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (id !== '') {
    foo(id)
  }
}, [id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `id` is always supposed to be in lock step with `orders[0]`, then i recommend you only have one state variable, not two. The `id` can just be a computed value:

```
const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
const id = orders[0] ? orders[0].userID : '';

// ...
.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
  const arr = [];
  arr.push({
    id: snapshot.id,
    ...snapshot.data(),
  });
  setOrders(arr);
});
```

If instead there are some cases where `id` and `orders[0]` are supposed to be unrelated, then you'll need to keep them in two states, but you may need to batch setting the state. In many cases, react can batch calls to set state automatically, but for this to happen, code execution needs to begin within react, such as from a useEffect callback or an onClick event.

In your code, the setStates are happening in an `onSnapshot` callback, which will happen whenever firebase decides it should happen, and react doesn't know about it. React can't batch these together since it doesn't know what's going on. But you can tell react to batch the changes as follows:

```
import { unstable_batchedUpdates } from "react-dom";

// ...

.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
  const arr = [];
  arr.push({
    id: snapshot.id,
    ...snapshot.data(),
  });
  unstable_batchedUpdates(() => {
    setID(arr[0].userID);
    setOrders(arr);
  });
});
```

The "unstable" bit of the name is just an indication that they may change this api in the next major version, so you'll want to check the patch notes if you update your version of react.